# Perform Division using VBA script

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to perform a division using the below VBA script and it works fine, however I would like to freeze the formula cell for the column. eg: I have values from columns `A` to `BE` multiple rows and I would like the cell `BB3` to capture the value of `G3/E3` and the all the rows in column `BB` to capture the values to the above corresponding rows, so

```
BB3 = G3/E3, BB4 = G4/E4, BB5 = G5/E5
```

and so on..any help would be appreciated :)

```
Macro4 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+h
'
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-47]/RC[-49]*100"
    Range("BB3").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("BA3").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Range("BB4").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
    Range("BB3:BB4").Select
    Range("BB4").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("BB3").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Try grabbing the + handle of your formula cell with the mouse, and dragging down the column.  The formula will be copied, with relative references.

Comment: How can you tell that the "formula cell for the column" is not frozen?

Comment: My sheet has another macro which does vlookup and inserts a column and updates the lookup value in it, every time the row is inserted since the formula is constant it is not considering G3/E3 instead it becomes I3/G3 and so on and hence, I want it to be fixed to G3/E3 no matter even on additions of new columns.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet

With ws.Range("BB3:BB98")
    .Formula = "G3/E3"
    .Value = .Value
    .NumberFormat = "0"
End With
```

Comment: Hi User3271518..the above will not satisfy my requirement as this would only update column BB but my macro has more...it also inserts column with vlookup value and the column keeps shifting to right and so I want it to be dynamic on the column but the formula in it should always be G3/E3

Comment: the example given of BB3 = G3/E3, BB4 = G4/E4, BB5 = G5/E5  is satisfied by the code i submitted.  looking at this comment and the one above adjust your question to reflect a more accurate depiction of what you are looking for.  Do you need the range your updating to be dynamic and change as you add columns or the formula to be dynamic and change with the addition of columns...please explain and provide an example if you can.

Comment: I was able to figure the solution out....I used a work around ;), however thank you for your replies :)

Comment: is your workaround related to this answer? upvote it. and post your own answer.

Comment: what's `.Value = .Value` for?

Comment: so the .value = .value makes it so the cell isnt a formula but it is a value.  This helps because leaving it as a formula makes it harder to manipulate.